# Is the surface $z=\ln \cos x-\ln \cos y$ minimal?

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Is the surface $z=\ln \cos x-\ln \cos y$ minimal?

I found the partial derivatives:

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-\mathrm{tg}x,\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\mathrm{tg}y,\frac{\partial ^2z}{\partial x^2}=-\mathrm{sec}^2x,\frac{\partial ^2z}{\partial y^2}=\mathrm{sec}^2y$$

After that I used the formulas for the main curvature:

$$E=1+\left ( \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right )^2=1+\mathrm{tg}^2x=\mathrm{sec}^2x$$
$$F=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=-\mathrm{tg}x\mathrm{tg}y$$
$$G=1+\left ( \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \right )^2=1+\mathrm{tg}^2y=\mathrm{tg}^2y$$
$$L=\frac{\partial ^2z}{\partial x^2}:E=-\frac{\mathrm{sec}^2x}{\mathrm{sec}^2x}=-1$$
$$M=\frac{\partial ^2z}{\partial x\partial y}:E=0, \; \frac{\partial ^2z}{\partial x\partial y}=0$$
$$N=\frac{\partial ^2z}{\partial y^2}:G=\frac{\mathrm{sec}^2y}{\mathrm{sec}^2y}=1$$

The average curvature is calculated as follows
$$H=\frac{k_1+k_2}{2}\Rightarrow k_1,k_2=\frac{L+N}{2}\pm \sqrt{\left ( \frac{L-N}{2} \right )^2+M}$$

*Did I use the formulas correctly? I feel that I made a mistake in the calculation or in the formula itself, maybe the formula for the average curvature is different?*

Comment: $k_i$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix $\text{I}^{-1}\text{II}$, not of the matrix $\text{II}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula for calculating the mean curvature:

$H = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\left\|\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial v}\right\|}{\left\|\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{r}}{\partial r^2}\right\|} \nabla^2 r^2$

and you can let your functions be functions of the complex variable $z$.

Since your equation satisfies the Laplacian equation:

$\nabla^2  z = \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}  = 0$

you get that

$H = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\left\|\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial v}\right\|}{\left\|\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{r}}{\partial r^2}\right\|}0 = 0$.

Since every surface that has zero mean curvature is a minimal surface, that must mean that your function's surface is a minimal surface.

Good luck!

Comment: But $\nabla^2  (\ln \cos x - \ln \cos y) = -\sec ^2 x + \sec ^2y \neq 0$.

Comment: But if you look at it as if it is a complex function of the variable z than $-\sec^2 z + \sec^2 z = 0$

Comment: There is no complex function here. Can you show us how you calculate $\nabla^2 z$?

Comment: The function $f(x,y)=z=\ln(\cos(x)) - \ln(\cos(y))$ is indeed not a complex function, but I tried of thinking that it was, so that we could use the formula for H. But now I see that when we look at it as if it was complex it only has one variable z and it cancels out and becomes a constant function. Than it satisfies the Laplace equation trivially. I am not so sure now if my technique is legal anymore.